# CSS-moving text from left to right

Tags: css, animation, marquee, keyframe

I want to create an animated HTML "marquee" that scrolls back and forth on a website:

```
<div class="marquee">This is a marquee!</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.marquee {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-animation: rightThenLeft 4s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightThenLeft {
    0%   {left: 0%;}
    50%  {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: 0%;}
}
```

The problem is, the marquee doesn't stop when it reaches the right-hand edge of the screen; it moves all the way off the screen (making a horizontal scroll bar appear, briefly) and then comes back.

So, how do I make the marquee stop when its right-hand edge reaches the right-hand edge of the screen?

EDIT: Oddly, this does not work:

```
50% {right: 0%}
```

Comment: use javascript to stop the animation using css property

Comment: @Webtecher how would the javascript know when to stop the animation?

Comment: Instead of left: 100% it should be left: `100% - ( number of characters in string * space taken by single character )`  Now, obviously you will not do such things in css. So better instead of using `left` or `right` , use `margin-left` or `margin-right`.

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't work, even if you change my code to `margin-left`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I got it to work by using margin-right, and setting it to move from right to left.
http://jsfiddle.net/gXdMc/

Don't know why for this case, margin-right 100% doesn't go off the screen. :D
(tested on chrome 18)

EDIT: now left to right works too http://jsfiddle.net/6LhvL/

Comment: Yeah this works, thanks :). Hopefully someone can comment on why this is the case. I think it's because of your {text-align: right;}

Comment: @tanis.control see my comment in your question.

Comment: note that changing the css to using `text-align:left` and `margin-left` doesn't produced desired outcome. Only works with `text-align: right` and `margin-right`. I've edited my answer for the direction you wanted :)

Comment: What if the text is bigger than the container? The text does not move all together. http://jsfiddle.net/sj3k6kgu/

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use [CSS animated text generator](http://cssload.net/en/animated_text). There are pre-created templates already

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can achieve your result with use of  `<marquee behavior="alternate"></marquee>`

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<marquee behavior="alternate"><span class="marquee">This is a marquee!</span></marquee>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    max-width: 400px;
    background: green;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: right;
}

.marquee {
    background: red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-animation: rightThenLeft 4s linear;
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/gXdMc/6/

Comment: Unfortunately, deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I like using the following to prevent things being outside my `div` elements. It helps with CSS rollovers too.

```
.marquee{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

this will hide anything that moves/is outside of the div which will prevent the browser expanding and causing a scroll bar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you could create a wrapper around your marquee and then assign a `width` (or `max-width`) to the wrapping element. For example:

```
<div id="marquee-wrapper">
    <div class="marquee">This is a marquee!</div>   
</div>
```

And then `#marquee-wrapper { width: x }`.

Comment: I thought of this, too, but it doesn't work.

{left: 100%} makes it move all the way off the screen.

I wish I could do {left: 100% - 30px}

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the correct solution but I have achieved this 
by redefining .marquee class just after animation CSS.

Check below:

```
<style>
#marquee-wrapper{
    width:700px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid red;
}

div.marquee{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
position:relative;
animation:myfirst 5s;
-moz-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Firefox */
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */{
0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
100% {background:red; left:100%; top:0px}
}
div.marquee{ 
left:700px; top:0px
}
</style>

<!-- HTMl COde -->

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer and Opera.</p>
<div id="marquee-wrapper">
<div class="marquee"></div>
```