# Animate block back and forth within div continuously with CSS3 keyframes

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I'm trying to animate a span that moves back and forth enclosed within a div using CSS3 keyframes. Ideally, I'd like the keyframes to look something like this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes backandforth {
     0% {text-align:left;} 50%{text-align:right;} 100%{text-align:left;}
}
```

[**Demo in JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dofykw02/1/)

But since it's not possible to animate text-align, I've been searching for an alternative property that can be animated to reach the desired positioning. That's where I'm stuck at.

I tried setting the left property to 100% midway through the animation, but that ended up pushing the span off the div. I also tried animating the float property, but that didn't work.

Then I saw this question on [moving text from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679367/css-moving-text-from-left-to-right) and tried the JSFiddle from the top answer. While it looks like the solution, it unfortunately did not work for me since I want my animation to move continuously at ease, and for the last few seconds of that animation, the span stalls.

Comment: something like so ? http://jsfiddle.net/dofykw02/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### CSS Solution

you can play around the left position when the animation is at 50% like so :

because when you put it `left: 100%` it depend on the left corner of the span this is why it will go out the container `div`

```css
@-webkit-keyframes backandforth {0%{left:0;} 50%{left:58%;} 100%{left:0;}}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dofykw02/2/)**

I hope this fits your needs

#### JavaScript solution

```js
var thisis = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var tyty = document.getElementById("move");
var witth = tyty.offsetWidth;

thisis.style.paddingRight = witth +"px";
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dofykw02/4/)**

with this JS whatever you change the text it will still in the container div

Comment: Problem is, my program allows the span to dynamically change its width, so that wouldn't work out for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a pure-CSS way to do it if you combine absolute positioning `left` with simultaneous `transform: translate`.

https://jsfiddle.net/cd7kjwy6/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* ---------------- relevant CSS ---------------- */
.animated {
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.animated__text {
  position: absolute;
  animation: 3s bounce ease-in-out infinite paused;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.animated:not(.animated--on-hover) .animated__text,
.animated.animated--on-hover:hover .animated__text {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 5%, 95%, 100% {
        left: 0%;
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    45%, 55% {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
  <span class="animated__text">animate me!</span>
</div>
<div class="animated  mt-2">
  <span class="animated__text">Longcat is looooooooooooooooooong!</span>
</div>
<div class="animated  mt-2">
  <span class="animated__text">~</span>
</div>
<div class="animated  animated--on-hover  mt-2">
  <span class="animated__text">only on hover</span>
</div>
```

---

If you wanted to snap the "hover" variant back to the original position, you could use something like this (or JavaScript for a proper reset):

```
.animated.animated--on-hover:not(:hover) .animated__text {
  left: 0 !important;
  transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To infinitely animate a node back-and-forth use the `alternate infinite` values for the `animate` property which points to a `@keyframes` rule with only `1` keyframe, which represent the end-state (in the below case moving a `div` to the right-side).

Note that in the below example I intentionally did not use `position` but used the "new" (as of writing) [`container` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type) which opens up the usage for *container size units* `translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%))`

The first `div` (top-most) is relative to the `body` element, and the second `div` is relative to the `fieldset` (its wrapper), because both the `body` and the `fieldset` has the `container` property applied.

```css
body {
  container-type: size;
}

div {
 display: inline-block;
 outline: 1px solid red;
 animation: move 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

/* or inside a container */
fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@keyframes move {
  to { transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%)) }
}
```

```html
<div>I'm moving!</div>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Inside a container</legend>
  <div>I'm moving!</div>
</fieldset>
```